# Package dependencies on sub process

Tags: pip, package, ironpython, revitpythonshell

With subprocess module iam trying to call c-python from iron python and pipe the output back to iron python.

I am working on iron python IDE inside dynamo for revit,I have a c-python script in my desktop and running it.

The question is how do i make sure if the packages in the c- python is available with the end user? Since the end users will not be comfortable going to cmd prompt and install every package(civil engineers may not even know about this) I am searching for a way to open cmd in background with iron python and install the necessary package if they were not previously installed.